# Dos campos con ManyToManyField que hacen referencia al mismo modelo se replican

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo de usuario, que hereda de `AbstractUser`, mi página es tecnicamente un clon de Instagram y necesitaba agregar la funcionalidad de seguir asi que agregue estos dos fields al modelo de usuario.

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField('self')
following = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

El problema es que cuando agrego objetos a la lista de followers o a la de following, se replican los datos y sinceramente no he encontrado un error a simple vista, ya probe poniendo un `related_name` y no funciona.

Sería grandioso que me pudieran ayudar, les dejo los dos métodos de la clase tanto para seguir a un usuario como para dejar de seguir.

```
def follow(self, user):
    """Function that allows this model to follow an user.
    Receive two parameters:
        -self --> The user who called this function and who is going to follow another.
        -user --> The user who will start to be followed.
    """

    try:

        self.following.add(user)
        user.followers.add(self)

    except Exception as e:

        print(type(e).__name__)
        return False
    else:
        return True

def unfollow(self, user):
    """Function that allows this model to unfollow an user.
    Receive two parameters:
        -self --> The user who called this function to stop following another.
        -user --> The user who is going to stop being followed
    """

    try:
        self.following.remove(user)
        user.followers.remove(self)

    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e).__name__)
        return False

    else:
        return True
```

Comment: podrias usar algo como esto:  followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserClass', related_name='followers_user')...

Comment: Tengo bastante tiempo sin tocar Django, y ya vi que te dieron una respuesta muy acertada, pero como consejo, creo que pudiste hacer eso con un solo campo y complicarte menos `following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers')`. De esa forma tienes la relación `following` para los que sigues, y tienes la inversa `followers` para los que te siguen. Espero no errar con el comentario, porque te hablo en base a lo que me acuerdo, y créeme que así te evitas código redundante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que al usar `ManyToManyField` apuntando a `self`, es decir, a la misma clase, entonces por defecto Django asume que esta relación es simétrica. Es decir, si tu me sigues, yo te sigo. Para que esto no pase en tu situación simplemente tienes que indicarle que no quieres que se comporte de esta forma:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```

Prueba con estos cambios y debería funcionar como quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si bien me ayudo bastante al final lo he dejado asi para evitar redundancia como bien decia @German Alazate    `followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False,related_name='following')` He agregado el  `symmetrical=False` para evitar que los dos campos se tomen como el mismo ya que de lo contrario no me dejaba mantener esa relacion inversa. Muchas gracias a todos ;)